# blade template, @yield() in @yield

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-opengraph, laravel-blade

This is my current implementation of the Open Graph tags using Laravel 5:

**app.blade.php**

```
<title>@yield('title')</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="@yield('og-title', 'DEFAULT PAGE TITLE')">
<meta property="og:image" content="@yield('og-image', 'default.png')">
<meta property="og:url" content="@yield('og-url', '{{ Request::url() }}')">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SITE NAME">
```

**page.blade.php**

```
@extends('app')
@section('title', $article->title . ' | SITE NAME')
@section('og-title', $article->title)
@section('og-image', secure_url('img/news/' . $article->image .'.png'))
```

It works for the most part, but I have a couple inquiries:

1. Is there a way to use `@yield()` in `@yield`?

   I tried `<meta property="og:title" content="@yield('og-title', @yield('title'))">` but it did not work.
2. How can I get the current SECURE url of the page?

   `{{ Request::url() }}` returns `http://example.com/page`, but I want `https://example.com/page`

As a meta, please let me know if you have any suggestions to improve my current method of OG.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to achieve what you want. What you can do is to move the OG meta tags html to partial view, to which you can pass parameters on each page as you wish. For example in your master layout just create section for the og tags:

**app.blade.php**

```
<title>@yield('title')</title>
@section('ogtags')

@show
```

Now create your partial view let's call it:

**og_tags.blade.php**

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ $title or 'DEFAULT PAGE TITLE' }}">
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ $image or 'default.png' }}">
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ isset($url) ? $url : str_replace('http://', 'https://', Request::url()) }}">
```

So now in you views you can easily add og-tags like this:

**home.blade.php**

```
@extends('app')

@section('ogtags')
    @include('og_tags', ['title' => 'my title', 'image' => 'my-image.png'])
@stop

@section('content')
     your content here
@stop
```

For the secure url question, `Request::url()` returns the current url of the page, if it is via HTTPS it will start with `https://` otherwise it will start with `http://`. So this is why I just replace it to always be https

```
str_replace('http://', 'https://', Request::url())
```

If you wish to always have og_tags (in case your view does not define this section and you want to show default ones) you can just modify your **app.blade.php** like this:

```
<title>@yield('title')</title>
@section('ogtags')
    @include('og_tags')
@show
```

This is the cool part of [Blade](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates) that you can split everything in smaller parts, then include them with dynamic parameters, or just create view composers to handle the data.

Answer (score 0):

I always use a `meta.blade.php` and keep my `meta` separate from the main layout and not only `meta` but also, `styles` and `scripts` when possible and include then using `@include(...)`, anyways, but how to make it dynamic? In this case i use a similar approach like you but a little differently which let me full flexibility to make it real dynamic. Here is how I do it, probably it'll answer what you are seeking here. So, let's create a 'meta.blade.php' file and mine is given below:

```
<!-- Title-->
<title>@yield('title', smart('site.title'))</title>
<!-- Meta-->
<meta name="keywords" content="@yield('keywords', getSiteMeta('keywords'))" />
<meta name="description" content="@yield('description', getSiteMeta('description'))" />
<meta name="author" content="@yield('author', getSiteMeta('author'))" />
<!-- CSRF for AJAX-->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Notice  `@yield('keywords', getSiteMeta('keywords'))` so here; the `getSiteMeta` is a helper function which is declared in my `app\Helpers\Common.php` file and the function looks like this:

```
/**
 * Prapare meta Tags by $name
 * 
 * @param  String $metaname Meta Name
 * @return Meta Content
 */
function getSiteMeta($name)
{
    return smart("site.meta.$name");
}
```

Also another function is involved here, which is:

```
/**
 * Short cut to config call for smart.php file items
 * @param  String $str Config Key
 * @return String Config Value
 */
function smart($str)
{
    return config("smart.$str");
}
```

Actually, I've a config file of my own at `config\smart.php` and `smart` is my site name so I've kept all of my site related configs in `config\smart.php` which looks like this:

```
// config/smart.php
return [

    'site' => [
        'name' => 'Smart',
        'title' => 'Smart Title',
        'tagline' => 'Smart Tag Line',
        'meta' => [
            'keywords' => 'Smart Keywords',
            'language' => 'english',
            'description' => '...',
            'author' => 'Sheikh Heera'
        ],
    ],

    'role' => [
        'default' => 'genaral',  # By default, a user gets this role when registers.
        'reserved' => 'superuser' # Application's Admin must have this role assigned.
    ],
    // More...
];
```

Probably you got the idea, I can call `smart('key_name')` to get configs of my site so I don't need to use `config('smart.key')` and by default all the `meta` values are stored in my `config/smart.php` file so if I don't use a section like this:

```
@section('keywords')
    Some, Keywords, Here
@stop
```

Then I've always my default settings and by using a helper function `getSiteMeta` I have enough flexibility to change the logic of my function, for example, I can change the default source of my `meta` tags and can build it on the fly.

Regarding `https` it depends on your site, if you have used secured url (`ssl/https`) and `Request::url()` just returns what your current url is, so if it's `https` then it'll return that otherwise you'll get `http`.

Comment: Hey, I liked the dynamic structure that you have followed, but I am having doubt at functions that you called as a default value argument of `@yield()` i.e. like function `smart()` in `@yield('title', smart('site.title'))`, I mean, can you elaborate that, how can we use in the way you have shown, also, can we call controller method there?

Comment: You shouldn't call controller methods here.

Comment: Okay, I understand that, but how are you able to use functions from `app\Helpers\Common.php` in `@yield()`, Can you please elaborate this?

Comment: app\Helpers\Common.php is available as globally so you can call any global function from anywhare.